Formatting horizontal line and text overlapping in table for revtex

\documentclass[reprint,amsmath,amssymb,aps,onecolumn]{revtex4-2}


\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \caption{\label{tab:2} Parameter values of linear and non-linear Regge trajectories of $(n_{r},M^{2})$, Natural $(J,M^{2})$ and Un-Natural $(J,M^{2})$ planes for $b\bar{b}$ bound system}
    \begin{ruledtabular}
        \begin{tabular}{c|c|cc|ccc}
            \multirow{2}{*}{Plots} & \multirow{2}{*}{Trajectory} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Linear} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Non-linear}  
            \\
            \cline{3-7}
            &  & $\beta (\text{Gev})^{-2}$  & $\beta_{0}$ & $\tau (\text{ Gev})^{-2}$ & $\tau_{0}$ & $\tau_{1}$ 
            \\
            \hline
            \multirow{3}{*}{$(n_{r},M^{2})$} & $n^{3}S_{1}$ &  &  &  &  &   
            \\
            & $n^{3}P_{2}$ &  &  &  &  &  
            \\
            & $n^{3}D_{1}$ &  &  &  &  &  
            \\
            \hline
            &  & $\alpha (\text{Gev})^{-2}$  & $\alpha_{0}$ & $\gamma (\text{ Gev})^{-2}$ & $\gamma_{0}$ & $\gamma_{1}$
            \\
            \cline{3-7}
            \multirow{6}{*}{\makecell{Natural\\ Parity\\ $(J,M^{2})$}} & Parent &  &  &  &  & 
            \\
            & $1^{\text{st}}$ Daughter &  &  &  &  & 
            \\
            & $2^{\text{nd}}$ Daughter &  &  &  &  & 
            \\
            & $3^{\text{rd}}$ Daughter &  &  &  &  & 
            \\
            & $4^{\text{th}}$ Daughter &  &  &  &  & 
            \\
            & $5^{\text{th}}$ Daughter &  &  &  &  & 
            \\
            \hline
            &  & $\alpha (\text{Gev})^{-2}$  & $\alpha_{0}$ & $\gamma (\text{ Gev})^{-2}$ & $\gamma_{0}$ & $\gamma_{1}$
            \\
            \cline{3-7}
            \multirow{6}{*}{\makecell{Un-Natural\\ Parity\\ $(J,M^{2})$}} & Parent &  &  &  &  & 
            \\
            & $1^{\text{st}}$ Daughter &  &  &  &  &
            \\
            & $2^{\text{nd}}$ Daughter &  &  &  &  & 
            \\
            & $3^{\text{rd}}$ Daughter &  &  &  &  & 
            \\
            & $4^{\text{th}}$ Daughter &  &  &  &  & 
            \\
            & $5^{\text{th}}$ Daughter &  &  &  &  & 
            \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{ruledtabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}

The cline is not spanning the rows properly and it is overlapping the text. The data is not properly centered. I am using revtex 4.2.

Welcome to TeX.SE, please provide the MWE as in executable format, i.e., from \documentclass to \end{document}

(please reconsider the layout, it would look much better without all these vertical lines)

Better try with \cmidrule instead of \cline

Thankyou :) @MadyYuvi. I have edited the question let me know if it is ok

\cmidrule is also not working

Show code with \cmidrule

sure i will try it without vertical lines once @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

Use \cmidrule and replace all the \hline and remove all vertical rules, no-one used those vertical rule professionally anymore.

This works just fine
\documentclass[reprint,amsmath,amssymb,aps,onecolumn]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \caption{\label{tab:2} Parameter values of linear and non-linear Regge trajectories of $(n_{r},M^{2})$, Natural $(J,M^{2})$ and Un-Natural $(J,M^{2})$ planes for $b\bar{b}$ bound system}
    \begin{ruledtabular}
        \begin{tabular}{c c cc ccc}
            \multirow{2}{*}{Plots} & \multirow{2}{*}{Trajectory} & \multicolumn{2}{c }{Linear} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Non-linear}  
            \\
            \cmidrule{3-7}
            &  & $\beta (\text{Gev})^{-2}$  & $\beta_{0}$ & $\tau (\text{ Gev})^{-2}$ & $\tau_{0}$ & $\tau_{1}$ 
            \\
            \midrule
            \multirow{3}{*}{$(n_{r},M^{2})$} & $n^{3}S_{1}$ &  &  &  &  &   
            \\
            & $n^{3}P_{2}$ &  &  &  &  &  
            \\
            & $n^{3}D_{1}$ &  &  &  &  &  
            \\
            \midrule
            &  & $\alpha (\text{Gev})^{-2}$  & $\alpha_{0}$ & $\gamma (\text{ Gev})^{-2}$ & $\gamma_{0}$ & $\gamma_{1}$
            \\
            \cmidrule{3-7}
            \multirow{6}{*}{\makecell{Natural\\ Parity\\ $(J,M^{2})$}} & Parent &  &  &  &  & 
            \\
            & $1^{\text{st}}$ Daughter &  &  &  &  & 
            \\
            & $2^{\text{nd}}$ Daughter &  &  &  &  & 
            \\
            & $3^{\text{rd}}$ Daughter &  &  &  &  & 
            \\
            & $4^{\text{th}}$ Daughter &  &  &  &  & 
            \\
            & $5^{\text{th}}$ Daughter &  &  &  &  & 
            \\
            \midrule
            &  & $\alpha (\text{Gev})^{-2}$  & $\alpha_{0}$ & $\gamma (\text{ Gev})^{-2}$ & $\gamma_{0}$ & $\gamma_{1}$
            \\
            \cmidrule{3-7}
            \multirow{6}{*}{\makecell{Un-Natural\\ Parity\\ $(J,M^{2})$}} & Parent &  &  &  &  & 
            \\
            & $1^{\text{st}}$ Daughter &  &  &  &  &
            \\
            & $2^{\text{nd}}$ Daughter &  &  &  &  & 
            \\
            & $3^{\text{rd}}$ Daughter &  &  &  &  & 
            \\
            & $4^{\text{th}}$ Daughter &  &  &  &  & 
            \\
            & $5^{\text{th}}$ Daughter &  &  &  &  & 
            \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{ruledtabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}


Use \cmidrule and replace all the \hline and remove all vertical rules, i used this and it works fine now. Thank you for your help

@AnshulBokade  Use can use \midrule for the \hline's in this case. The booktabs rules give better spacing at the cost of not working with vertical lines. Do read the booktabs manual if you want a better splitting under the two headlines covered by \cmidrule

Yes that is what it was not working for me when i had vertical lines but it worked just fine when i removed it. I didnt know about this.

@AnshulBokade Do remember proper terms, "does not work" usially means that the code does not compile. Here is does compile, the output just does not look at its best.

Sure, i will keep it in mind @daleif. Thankyou
